# Fast, free tool to unarchive any compression format?

Tags: linux, compression

I've been using (Ubuntu's) file-roller to compress a range of files, e.g. .gz, .zip, .rar, .tar.gz, etc. It's nice because it provides a simple, uniform interface to de-compressing files in particular folders. However, it's pretty slow, apparently because it pops open a GUI window to tell you its uncompressing the file.

So I am wondering if anyone can recommend a tool that will uncompress multiple compression formats, and has a uniform interface?

Comment: Not programming related?

Comment: It is a tool that can assist with programming (packaging of programs) in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) can uncompress a wide variety of formats, including 7z, ZIP, GZIP, BZIP2, TAR, ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, DEB, DMG, HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MSI, NSIS, RAR, RPM, UDF, WIM, XAR and Z.

Comment: The 7zip package on Ubuntu does not provide a GUI, although its counterpart on Windows is one of my favourites.

Comment: 7z on Ubuntu seems to do what I need ... now I just have to figure out why it gets stuck decompressing some (but not all!) .rar files. :-(

Answer (score 2):

If using 7zip as a developer don't forget you can easily embed it in your own applications. Scroll down to "[How can I add support for 7z archives to my application?](http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html)" in that link. Great stuff gotta love 7zip. If you want an app to build on with a uniform interface 7zip is it. Not to mention its a [SF project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/) so you can take a look around if you like.

Answer (score 1):

File-roller is simply a front-end to these file formats. It sits on top and parses the output from the compression programs. I doubt you will get any noticeable performance advantages by replacing it.

You could just go into the terminal, bypass the GUI and write, for an example:

> unrar x -r mybig.archive.rar
>   tar xvfz mybig.archive.tar.gz
>   unzip mybig.archive.zip

**Update: Ran a test (1.4G rar archive)**

- unrar (non-free): 1m25.207s
- file-roller: 1m39.311s
- 7z-rar: 1m17.084s
- unrar-free: failed
- rar (shareware): 1m29.109s

14 extra seconds for a full front-end, I think it is acceptable. 7zip is fastest, without frontend.

Comment: Indeed. However, file-roller pops up a GUI window for each file it opens, and some simple experiments suggest that this is what takes most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Windows : Universal Extractor -  is an application destined to extract virtually **any type** of archive available in today’s market: RAR, ZIP, 7Z, EXE, TAR, NRG, ISO, DLL, you name it; this program is able to process all of them at incredible speed.

There’s no other purpose to this program than extracting the contents of archives. As such, you cannot rely on it to create archives. Also, the number of files it can process simultaneously is restricted to one, so batch decompressing is not possible.

7zip can do the simple job, but not like Universal Extractor

Ubuntu: p7zip-rar or p4zip or Archive Manager